# Pymongo - convert datatype and find max

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I have written the below aggregate query in pymongo to get the highest value from column "**high**" and lowest value from column **low** .

```
db.bseadjprice.aggregate([
                            {
                                "$match": 
                                {
                                    "date" : {"$in":['2012-03-15 00:00:00.000', '2012-03-16 00:00:00.000']},
                                    "scripcode":"533159"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "$group" : 
                                {
                                    "_id" : "$scripcode", 
                                    "high":{"$max":"$high"}, 
                                    "low":{"$min":"$low"}
                                }
                            }
                        ])
```

since the values are in sting i am getting incorrect values.

Is there any way to solve this like putting "int($**low**)" and get the correct answer ?

Thanks.

Comment: unless you can convert your collection to have integer values in these fields, you will not be able to get correct results, as there is no type converting operator in aggregate() - $project:{ihigh:{$add:["$high",0]}} returns an error.

If you cannot convert the data in the collection, you could use mapReduce() instead, see the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could change the `$type` of the field for the whole collection and than run your query.

Comment: In my case this is not possible. I have followed @ronasta's suggestion.